# android notification for sms app

Tags: android, sms, android-notifications

I am creating sms app and I want to have diff notification for each phone number. Also each notification should show no of unread msg count in the msg. I am using this code but it removes the old notification and replaces it with new one.

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // ---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    String str2 = "";
    if (bundle != null) {
        // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            str2 += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            // str2 += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
        }

        Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(str2));
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,
                new String[] { ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME }, null,
                null, null);
        try {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String displayName = c.getString(0);
            str2 = displayName;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, i, 0);

        String uri = "tel:" + str2;
        Intent iph = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(uri));
        PendingIntent pCall = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, iph, 0);

        // Build notification

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(str))
                .setContentTitle("New sms from " + str2)
                .setContentText(str)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_chat)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_call, "Call", pCall)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_accept, "Read", pIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_action_discard, "Delete", pIntent)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        // notification
        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
    }
}
```

}

so how can I fix this and show the notification count.
Also when I click on some action notification wont disappear. How to fix that.
Thank you

Comment: Did the solution work ?

Comment: i havent tried it yet i will post a comment when i will check it

Answer (score 0):

```
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

The `0` that you've put here is the id for your notification. So, if you use `0` for every notification the notifications will keep getting replaced. The idea would be to use a different id for every notification.

Comment: how do I set diff id for every notification. would it work if i just put any number there like notificationManager.notify(10, noti) or should i generate some random number and put it there. also how can i remove the notification when some action is clicked please share if you know.

Comment: You can use any random number for notification id. Just make sure they arent already being used otherwise the previous notification will get removed.

Comment: how can i keep a map of phone number and its notification id cause if i put random id for everytime i get a sms it will create diff notifications for same number

Comment: If you want to temporarily store it, you can just use a hash map but I think you'd want to save it across multiple sessions. In that case, you can use the sqlite database to save the phone number with the corresponding randomly generated ID.